# appending a dataset to a session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session

I know how to add a dataset to a session

```
Dataset ds = GetResults();
Session["xyz "] = ds;
```

Is there a way I can append a dataset to a session ?

I am trying to do something like

```
  Session["xyz"] = ds + ds1; //ds1 is another dataset 
or  Session["xyz"] = ds + (Dataset)Session["xyz"];
```

It throws an error .. is there a way to do it ?

Comment: What error does it throw...

Comment: it says a + operator cannot be applied to operands System.Data.Dataset and System.Data.Dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DataSet** objects have **Merge** method

```
((DataSet)Session["xyz"]).Merge(ds1) ;
```

Comment: But merge _merges_ tables with each other. I assume OP wants them to keep separate.

Comment: @TimSchmelter he uses the word "append" that means "add to the already existing dataset"

Comment: He wants to append it to the same session key which not necessarily means that he wants to merge all tables. However, your idea might be helpful anyway.

Comment: Yeah I am looking to append. The above code gives me an error cannot implicitly convert type void to object.

Comment: @SqlSamurai I edited the answer, there is no need to assign the MERGE method acts on the current calling object "this"

Answer (score 2):

You could store both `DataSets` in a `List<DataSet>` which you can store in the session. Or you could use a `Tuple<DataSet, DataSet>`:

```
Session["xyz"] = Tuple.Create(ds1, ds2);
```

Later you can access them in this way:

```
var bothDataSets = (Tuple<DataSet, DataSet>)Session["xyz"];
DataSet d1 = bothDataSets.Item1;
DataSet d2 = bothDataSets.Item2;
```

However, why do you need to store such (normally) large objects in Session at all?

Comment: Heres my scenario . I have a grid view control and a drop down list. Each time there is an index change event on the drop down list , it fetches a row from the database. I would like to append this row to the already existing elements of the grid view , and for that I want to store the old elements in a session and each time there is an index change event, I will append the row to the session .. Let me know if you think there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are presumably seeing an error something like this.

Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Data.DataSet' and 'System.Data.DataSet'

The is no overload method that allows you to add DataSets are have to see why you would ever want to define one. I suppose you could create a collection of DataSet objects. Perhaps a dictionary, e.g.

```
Dictionary<DataSet> mydata = new Dictionary<DataSet>();
```

Then use Session to store/retrieve "mydata"